# Condition in XAML to change component

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've a combobox, which allows me to select a type. When I select a type, i'm able to fill a `component`. But I'd like that my component `corresponding to my type`. So, if it's a date, i'd like to display a `datepicker`, and if it's a string, i'd like to display a `textbox`.

How can I do that ?

I don't want to change things around `DataTemplate`, because this row is a part of a datagrid :)

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="SQLValue" Width="0.55*" CanUserResize="False" CanUserReorder="False">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                  <!-- HERE ! HOW CAN I CHOOSE ONE BY A CONDITION ? -->
                  <DatePicker/>
                  <TextBox Text="{Binding SqlValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for templating, i.e. make a different `DataTemplate` for each type, and then let the cell just automatically select the right template (or if you must, explicitly make the cell template a single `ContentControl`, which in turn will select the right template). What have you tried? What _specifically_ are you having trouble with? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly the answers to these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is: you should a property in data context call DispType (int)
Then in each control you binding Visibility with above property, include a Converter convert number to Visible or not, Converter have parameter is number.

You can see my eg:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Visibility="{Binding DispType, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityTypeConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}"/>
    <TextBox Visibility="{Binding DispType, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityTypeConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}"/>
    <DatePickerTextBox Visibility="{Binding DispType, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityTypeConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}"/>
</Grid>
```

You see the hard code for ConverterParameter.
And Converter class

```
public class VisibilityTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int actualType = parameter == null ? 0 : System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter);
        int compareType = value == null ? 0 : System.Convert.ToInt32(value);

        if (actualType == compareType)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

- Please not that code is only demo, you should change code to meet your expectation.

Comment: This is perfect dude ! Currently, it's a really smart way to do it, thanks !